# Tensorflow Object Detection API, update performance measurement

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am using Tensorflow Object Detection API to classify objects in the images. I am using own dataset. I am facing the problem of performance. I need a suggestion about the training strategy.

I have updated cocoapi\PythonAPI\pycocotools\cocoeval.py file to check mAP per class. After line 466 I have added these lines:

```
             if ap == 1:
                avg_ap = 0.0
                class_count = 0
                my_class_ids = p.catIds
                num_classes = len(my_class_ids)

                for i in range(0, num_classes):
                    my_mean = np.mean(s[:, :, i, :])
                    if my_mean > -1:
                        print('{}. category# {}: {}'.format(i, my_class_ids [i], my_mean))
                        avg_ap += my_mean
                        class_count += 1
                if class_count > 0:
                    print("Class average#{} mAP : {}".format(class_count, avg_ap / class_count))
```

The output looks like:

```
 11. category# 19: 0.183361433778217
 13. category# 21: 0.02725855003082726
 16. category# 24: 0.4594024961926443

 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.202
```

Here training data have examples: category# 19: 581, category# 21: 144 and category# 24: 453. So, data is a little bit skewed. I have used a pre-trained network trained with COCO data.

The network is learning, the loss is going down and mAP is 0.202. However, some object classes have very low mAP like 0.02 shown above.

How can I update my training strategy to improve performance measurement for those tough objects?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add more details and/or code, so that people can better understand what you do, Cheers

Comment: Hello, @Peter I have updated my question. Hope it will help.